# Arranging number of strings using Python's lambda function

Tags: python, string, lambda, cmp

```
a=['green egg','snail and lettuce','bacon','dorse naga','rutabaga ripple','cheese']
a.sort(cmp=lambda x,y:cmp(len(x),len(y)))
print a
```

Felt sorry for my ignorance, I don't understand how this lambda function is working, all I know about cmp is to give +1/1/0 to show the result of comparison,len gives the length of the string 
How did the lambda function take the arguments?  in pairs? taking in 1st,2nd then 3rd,4th ?
and what is the sort doing here?
Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's easier to understand using a regular function

```
def cmp_function(x, y):
    return cmp(len(x), len(y))

a = ['green egg','snail and lettuce','bacon','dorse naga','rutabaga ripple','cheese']
a.sort(cmp=cmp_function)
print a
```

The lambda function really isn't better that the regular function here. It's harder to document and test.

Aside: `cmp` is deprecated in Python2, so you should use a key function instead.

```
def key_function(x):
    return len(x)

a = ['green egg','snail and lettuce','bacon','dorse naga','rutabaga ripple','cheese']
a.sort(key=key_function)
print a
```

As in @Roman's answer, this `key_function` is just a wrapper around `len`, so you may write

```
a = ['green egg','snail and lettuce','bacon','dorse naga','rutabaga ripple','cheese']
a.sort(key=len)
print a
```

As an exercise, you could add a print statement to `cmp_function` and `key_function` - see how many times each is called. Compare this with the number of items in `a`

Comment: Did you mean `cmp(len(x), len(y))` rather than `map` there?

Comment: @abarnert, is that a rhetorical question? :)

Comment: Well, obviously you meant _something_ other than `map` (you know what you're doing, and you weren't trying to turn working code into a `TypeError`, so I can assume it was a simple typo…). But I wasn't 100% sure it was `cmp` you meant.

Comment: The idea of adding a `print` to the `cmp` and `key` functions to see what they actually get called with is great. I was going to suggest using [a visualizer](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html), but this is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3):

why not use `key`?

```
a = ['green egg','snail and lettuce','bacon','dorse naga','rutabaga ripple','cheese']
a.sort(key=len)
```

If you want to use old-style sorting with `cmp`, you have do define function cmp [like this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/):

> That function should take two arguments to be compared and then return
>   a negative value for less-than, return zero if they are equal, or
>   return a positive value for greater-than

so in your case it could be something like:

```
a = ['green egg','snail and lettuce','bacon','dorse naga','rutabaga ripple','cheese']
a.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: len(x) - len(y))
```

This function used to compare two elements in comparison-based sort ([Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: This explains why his code doesn't work, and how he can fix it. But his code _does_ work. So you're explaining the wrong thing. Still a great explanation of how to do it better, but…

Comment: @abarnert thanks, missed that point, +1 for you for explanation

Answer (score 1):

Roman Pekar explains how you *should* do this.

But why does your version work?

---

There are two different things named `cmp` here:

```
a.sort(cmp=lambda x,y:cmp(len(x),len(y)))
```

First, that `cmp=` means you're passing a function as a keyword argument named `cmp`. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) explain (in note 8):

> cmp specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (list items) which should return a negative, zero or positive number depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than, equal to, or larger than the second argument: cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x.lower(), y.lower()). The default value is None.

Second, what you're passing to that is a wrapper around the builtin [`cmp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp) function, which does this:

> Compare the two objects x and y and return an integer according to the outcome. The return value is negative if x < y, zero if x == y and strictly positive if x > y.

So, you're saying that to compare two list items `x` and `y`, it should call `cmp(len(x), len(y))`. In other words, sort them by length.

---

If you don't understand how `lambda x, y: cmp(len(x), len(y))` means that…

A `lambda` expression is just a way of defining simple functions in the middle of an expression. This:

```
lamdba a, b, c: <some expression>
```

… defines the exact same function as:

```
def f(a, b, c): return <expression>
```

… except that it doesn't have a name, and can be used in the middle of an expression. So, your `lambda` is the same as:

```
def f(x, y): return cmp(len(x), len(y))
```

The [Lambda forms](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) section of the tutorial explains this… although not in any more depth, and the [Lambdas](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) section of the reference docs is only slightly more detailed.

---

As gnibbler and Roman both point out, using `cmp` instead of `key` is deprecated (and illegal, in Python 3), and shouldn't be done unless you really need to work with Python 2.3 or earlier.

As gnibbler also points out, using `lambda` when you don't need to is a recipe for confusion.

So, Roman's answer is exactly what you *should* do instead of this.

The [Sorting HowTo](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) in the docs has a nice explanation of all of this.